# How can we extend pending actions view for Liferay Kaleo workflow?

Tags: liferay, workflow, liferay-6

I'm not sure whether it's feasible to do or not.

I want to customize the liferay-provided view to see pending actions for the workflow.

```
Liferay portal : 6.2-ce-ga2
Work flow engine: kaleo web
```

[EDITED]
notification-portlet comes as part of Liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2 and this comes to manage all workflow on gui. limitation with this that this comes with its own theme and view options. What I want, to have my own portlet which serves in place of in built portlet.

[here's](http://www.codeyouneed.com/liferay-custom-notifications/)  what I tried to override the notification bar which is also not working for me unfortunately. 
Apart from this I want to override the notification-portlet : I guess this is com.liferay.notifications.dockbarnotifications.poller.DockbarNotificationsPollerProcessor comes with notification-portlet.

Any hint or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you "want to customize"... What did you try so far? What is it that you need help on? Please provide the code that you already have, together with a description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, can you please have a look. What I want just an idea how to do this. I'm kinda clueless about this.